# Checking whether a given element is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: commutative-algebra, integral-extensions

How to see if $ x = \sqrt{2 +\sqrt{2}}+\dfrac{1}{2} \sqrt[3]{3}$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$ or not?? I don't think it is, as $\dfrac{1}{2}$ is not . But I am having trouble writing out an explicit proof.

Should I use any of the equivalent conditions like trying to show that $Z[x]$ is not a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$ module, etc??

Comment: The algebraic integers are closed under addition, subtraction, multiplication, and _roots_.

Comment: I have not been exposed to algebraic integers yet, actually I don't find it mentioned in the book I am using and no mention of the fact that you just used either. is there any other way of concluding?

Comment: An algebraic integer is just a complex number which is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The closure properties of the algebraic integers are standard knowledge, usually done right at the start, when they are first introduced. You can see by my answer how it simplifies the determination of whether or not $x$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks, I can see that my intuition stands precisely as 1/2 is not an  algebraic integer, right? Over $\mathbb{Z}$, there would be no monic polynomial as the only possibility is $2x-1 = 0$

Comment: Right, $\frac{1}{2}$ is not an algebraic integer. After all, what is its minimal monic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: However $\frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \sqrt{5}\right)$ _is_ an algebraic integer. How would you show that?

Comment: Let $x=\frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \sqrt{5}\right)$. Isolate $\sqrt{5}$, then square both sides. Then get everything on one side. The next step will be obvious. Thus, the minimal monic polynomial for $x$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is ...

Comment: Yeah, I had done a silly mistake in simple squaring...got it..thanks a ton for that example....answer would be $x^2 - x -1 =0$

Comment: Right, so the thing to note is that in this case, the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ didn't prevent integrality.

Comment: Yeah, thats why that example was an eye opener. I was running off with the idea that as long as a fraction was involved, one could safely conclude non integrality over $\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algebraic integers are closed under addition, subtraction, multiplication, and $n$-th roots, for any positive integer $n$.

It follows that $\sqrt{2 +\sqrt{2}}$ is an algebraic integer.

Let $x = \sqrt{2 +\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt[3]{3}$.

If $x$ is an algebraic integer, then

$${\small{\frac{1}{2}}} \sqrt[3]{3} = x - \sqrt{2 +\sqrt{2}}$$

is an algebraic integer, but then 
$\left(
{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}
 \sqrt[3]{3}\right)^3
$
is an algebraic integer, contradiction, since $\frac{3}{8}$ is not an algebraic integer.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$, as its monic irreducible polynomial is $x^4-4x^2+2$. Hence if $x$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$ then so is $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt[3]{3}=x-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$.

Similarly, $\sqrt[3]{9}$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$, hence if $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt[3]{3}$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$ then so is 
$$ \frac{1}{2}\sqrt[3]{3}\cdot\sqrt[3]{9}=\frac{3}{2} $$
But the only rational numbers which are integral over $\mathbb{Z}$ are the integers, so $\frac{3}{2}$ isn't integral over $\mathbb{Z}$, which implies that $x$ isn't integral either.

Comment: Thanks, but since quasi was helping me with the hints first, I thought it would be prudent to accept his answer.